# Who trained Yoda in the ways of the Force?

Tags: star-wars, yoda

I was looking through comics and the TV shows and I was wondering who trained Yoda in the ways of the Force. I could be wrong but I don't remember any mention of Yoda's master.

Comment: I felt that my answer to this one covered pretty much all of the known information about Yoda's training. Is there anything else you'd like me to focus on before considering an acceptance?

Answer (score 45):

Master Yoda mentions his master in the new [Junior novelisation](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/The_Empire_Strikes_Back:_So_You_Want_to_Be_a_Jedi%3F) of *Star Wars: The Empire Strikes Back*. Beyond that, there are no (Disney) canon references to the person who taught him:

> *Yoda chuckles. You don’t know why. You open your eyes and glance at his gnarled, withered body. His smile is as serene as the double sunset of Tatooine.
>   “Story heard I once,” he says. “From my master. True or not, I do not know. But good story. Listen you will.”
>   Yoda closes his eyes, inhales slowly, and begins.*

---

Moving down the canon scale, there are references to a Hysalrian Jedi Master named [N'Kata Del Gormo](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/N%27Kata_Del_Gormo) being Yoda's master. Leeland Chee (of the Star Wars Story Group) has noted that mentions of him are an "[in-universe legend](https://twitter.com/HolocronKeeper/status/322954211866333184)" and not to be considered canonical.

[image: image of N'Kata Del Gormo - four arms, holding a staff, snakelike lower body, with Yoda next to him]

Comment: Great answer to a good question. Also, no wonder why Yoda's master looks similar (only torso) to E.T. ^_^

Comment: E.T.'s species appeared in Episode 1 in the Senate on Coruscant, if I recall correctly, and don't look much like Hysalrians. http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Asogian

Comment: Ugh! Is it actually written in second person??

Comment: @ToddWilcox - The Luke Skywalker bits are. When we're with other characters it goes back into third person. Also, it's intercut with short stubs about Jedi training that are quite interesting and fun.

Answer (score 10):

While not Yoda's master, Huyang taught Yoda how to construct his lightsaber, possibly qualifying as "training him in the ways of the Force".

Huyang appeared in season five of *Star Wars: The Clone Wars*.

> We had quite an eventful mission.
> The most eventful since the time Master Yoda went to find his lightsaber crystal.
> --Huyang
> <sub>(*Star Wars: The Clone Wars 5x09, A Necessary Bond*)</sub>

[image: Huyang, a greyish-brown droid with a long face, a helmet-like domed head with two projections at the side where ears might be and glowing yellow eyes, has a giant red hand-drawn arrow pointing towards him.]

Comment: To be fair, he could have been going to get a new crystal because he lost his existing light saber, or something like that.  It's not clear from the quote that it was Yoda's first crystal.  Also, he says "Master Yoda."

Comment: @ScottWhitlock Valid points. Two things to consider, however: 1)Huyang had a different line which implied that he predated Yoda. 2)This seemed to have been intended as a parallel case, continuing the theme of Huyang's perpetualness.