# Who was Yoda's master?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends, yoda

Who was Yoda's master? Did his master live during the Jedi-Sith wars?

Comment: Answered here, except the last part: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/115171/who-trained-yoda-in-the-ways-of-the-force

Comment: The last part should be a separate question, though it is already (mostly) answered [here](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/102841/31936) and [here](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/102823/31936) (basically, Bane was dead before Yoda was alive). I've edited out the separate question, which means we can close this as a duplicate of the question @VerpinZal linked to.